# Sandbox Solutions, resetting the quota

Tags: sandbox-solution

I'm looking into the possibility of developing sandbox solutions (mainly web parts) for our SharePoint 2010 internet site. One thing that I keep reading is that if the quota is exceeded, then all sandbox solutions within the site collection will become unavailable until the quota is reset at midnight. Since this is an customer facing, internet site, we would not want this to ever happen. Ideally, when the warning email gets sent out, we would want an admin to somehow reset quota. Also, if the quota were ever exceeded and the sandbox was shutdown, we would want the admin to be able to restore the sandbox and reset the quota.

Is it possible to reset the quota for a sandbox that is nearing or has exceeded its quota? Also, feel free to comment on the wisdom of using sandbox solutions on an customer facing, internet site.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. It seems the consensus is that I should raise the quota to a value that I would never expect to exceed. However, in the event the threshold was exceeded, does anyone know of a way to bring the sandbox online while a solution to the problem is found?

Comment: If you are hitting the maximum possible quota, which seems highly unlikely, you can reconfigure the quota metrics from PowerShell as I mentioned in my answer (will add link).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quota is set in Central Administration -> Applications -> Site Collections -> Quotas and locks. You can set the limit for the site collection and the level at which an email is sent to the admin.

You can set it to a very high value. You can also set the resource quotas by using PowerShell, and also [set the metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335711.aspx) used to arrive at the resource point usage, although this is at the farm level. You could use this to disable quota limits altogether, but if you do that you might as well just deploy them as farm solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply set the maximum quota to a level that will never be reached in a day?

One word of wisdom is to know how many people will be visiting your site :)

Comment: The maximum quota value is 999999. One million minus one. I'd say that if you reach that in a day, you have quite a big server farm.

Comment: And most likely very poorly written code!

Comment: Wictor, reading your book is actually what led me to ask this question :)  Specifically section 7.3, the 2nd paragraph. BTW, thanks for the great coverage on partially trusted solutions!

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for *resetting* and not *changing* the quota this is the way to do it (had the same problem because Sharepoint somehow gave me 34 billion resource points, so changing the quota didn't work for me...) with Powershell:

```
# from http://www.threewill.com/2012/03/flooding-the-sandbox/
cls
$url = "http://servername/"
$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $url
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# timer job to reset daily status
$name = "job-solution-daily-resource-usage"
$job = Get-SPTimerJob | ?{$_.Name -match $name} | ?{$_.Parent -eq $WebApp}
Start-SPTimerJob -Identity $job
Write-Host $job.Name " startet"
```